# How do I show the percentage of amount saved

Tags: powerbi, analysis

Hi I have done the below analysis on power bi in matrix format:

| Region | Average payment amt | Average payment after removing report price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Region1 | 1756 | 1756 |
| Region2 | 1702 | 1640 |
| Region3 | 1619 | 1562 |

I  just want to show next to this the "percentage of the amount saved" for every region after removing the report price from the actual payment amount. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

add a column named as percentage

and use formula

Percentage Saved = ([payment amt] - [payment after removing report price]) / [payment amt]

Comment: Hi Could you please tell me how to do it in powerbi directly? with steps?

Comment: in you matrix right click and add a custom column and add this formula
after that in modeling tab click on the ribbon button and select percentage format .

Comment: You may want to consider using the DIVIDE() function instead of the '/' operator to handle div by 0 better.